# How to change java default icon of installer in java for mac installer

Tags: java, maven, javafx, maven-plugin, pom.xml

I have javafx application, I have successfully created the installer of application, but I want to change the java default icon of installer, So I have added
${basedir}/src/main/resources/images/logoIcon.ico
in pom.xml but it can not change,

The entire snap of pom.xml as follows:

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.testDemo</groupId>
<artifactId>test-app</artifactId>
<name>demo-app</name>

<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0</version>

<organization>
    <!-- Used as the 'Vendor' for JNLP generation -->
    <name>testDemo</name>
</organization>

<properties>
    <slf4j.version>1.6.1</slf4j.version>
    <springframework.version>3.2.2.RELEASE</springframework.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <configuration>

                <mainClass>com.testdemo.testapp.testApplication</mainClass>

                <!-- only required if signing the jar file -->
                <keyStoreAlias>example-user</keyStoreAlias>
                <keyStorePassword>example-password</keyStorePassword>
                <permissions>
                    <permission>all-permissions</permission>
                </permissions>
                <icon>${basedir}/src/main/resources/images/logoIcon.ico</icon>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>


<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.miglayout</groupId>
        <artifactId>miglayout-javafx</artifactId>
        <version>4.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.javadocmd</groupId>
        <artifactId>simplelatlng</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20090211</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

and for creating package, I use following commands,

1. mvn jfx:build-jar(it gives only jar of application)
2. mvn jfx:build-native (it gives .dmg file of application)

So please suggest me, how to change default installer icon for mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick look at [source code](https://github.com/zonski/javafx-maven-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/com/zenjava/javafx/maven/plugin/AbstractBundleMojo.java) make me think that the icon cannot be in a subdirectory (it seems to be a bug).

As a workaround, you can try to move your `logoIcon.ico` one directory upper (in `src/main/resources`)

If it doesn't work, you can also try to put it in `src/main/deploy/` (and not in a subdirectory)

To debug it, you can also run maven with the `-X` option and looking for the log:

`Using icon file at ...`

**But** be careful with this log since it will probably print the correct path while it seems that only the filename will be used to resolve the icon (i.e. sub dirs will be ignored)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but still not working, we are getting
[DEBUG] Using icon file at '/Users/Mac-5/flight-planner/src/main/deploy/logoIcon.ico' in debug log.
still icon can not change

Comment: so can you suggest solution for that issue?

Answer (score 3):

I added src/main/deploy/package/macosx/myapp.ico there and it finally worked :)

For you:

Create src/main/deploy/package/macosx/ folder
Add icon with name ${project.build.finalName}.ico
Run mvn jfx:build-native
I haven't played with it extensively - just got it to work and wanted to share. So if you want to use icon with different name, I don't know how. Not yet at least. The ... section in the config section seems to be for webstart, so I haven't been using it. Hope you get it to work!

Answered same at [How to set custom icon for javafx native package icon on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15880102/how-to-set-custom-icon-for-javafx-native-package-icon-on-windows/16477177#16477177)