# How to set custom icon for javafx native package icon on Windows

Tags: icons, javafx-2, native, exe, pom.xml

I am trying to chance the icon of the exe file while creating native bundling of javafx packaging.
I tried adding icon into pom.xml but till it wont work out for me as it gives default icon
Using Intellij IDEA IDE which contain an Pom.xml creating an package by `command = mvn jfx:build-native`
Here is my `pom.xml`:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <configuration>

                <mainClass>com.demoApp.testapp.testApplication</mainClass>

                <!-- only required if signing the jar file -->
                <keyStoreAlias>example-user</keyStoreAlias>
                <keyStorePassword>example-password</keyStorePassword>
                <permissions>
                    <permission>all-permissions</permission>
                </permissions>
                <icon>${basedir}/src/main/resources/images/logoIcon.ico</icon>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

I have added an icon path into pom.xml ${basedir}/src/main/resources/images/logoIcon.ico
that will run while native package execute but it wont work out for me

Is any other way to do it ?
 Please suggest.

---

i tried fx tags in pom.xml using ant,here is my changes in pom.xml

```
<properties>

<javafx.tools.ant.jar>${env.JAVA_HOME}\lib\ant-javafx.jar</javafx.tools.ant.jar> </properties>


<plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>create-launcher-jar</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <target xmlns:fx="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant">
                                <taskdef
                                        uri="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant"
                                        resource="com/sun/javafx/tools/ant/antlib.xml"
                                        classpath="${javafx.tools.ant.jar}"/>
                                <fx:application id="fxApp"
                                                name="${project.name}"
                                                mainClass="com.precisionhawk.flightplanner.FlightPlannerApp"/>
                                <fx:jar destfile="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-launcher">
                                    <fx:application refid="fxApp"/>
                                    <fx:fileset dir="${project.build.directory}/classes"/>
                                </fx:jar>
                                <attachartifact file="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-launcher.jar"
                                                classifier="launcher"/>
                                <fx:deploy>
                                    <fx:info>
                                        <fx:icon href="${basedir}/src/main/deploy/logoIcon.ico"></fx:icon>
                                    </fx:info>

                                </fx:deploy>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

but it wont work out..

Comment: the windows folder's name is missing in your code here: `<fx:icon href="${basedir}/src/main/deploy/logoIcon.ico"></fx:icon>`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I just struggled with the same issue using Zonsky's great javafx-maven-plugin. As of version 1.5, which you also were using, the src/main/deploy directory will be added to the classpath. The icon you want to use could be added there and it will be available on the classpath for the native builder!

I added src/main/deploy/package/windows/myapp.ico there and it finally worked :)

For you:

1. Create `src/main/deploy/package/windows/` folder
2. Add icon with name `${project.build.finalName}.ico`
3. Run `mvn jfx:build-native`

I haven't played with it extensively - just got it to work and wanted to share. So if you want to use icon with different name, I don't know how. Not yet at least. The `<icon>...</icon>` section in the config section seems to be for webstart, so I haven't been using it.
Hope you get it to work!

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at the logging while building a native app. That will tell you where the installer looks for the icon files and with wich name. For the default Windows native app it looks in ./package/windows/'appname'.ico 
Can't remember where 'appname' comes from, but just look at the logging while building, it will tell you. (I use the Ant targets called from my pom btw)

Comment: log while building a native app:
[INFO] Building Native Installers
[DEBUG] Using icon file at 'C:\Projects\DemoApp\src\main\deploy\logoIcon.ico'
its getting an path proper but the package icon is set to default icon

Comment: Creating app bundle: Facewizz in c:\dev\repositories\profile_planner\profileplanner\target\dist\bundles
  Using custom package resource [application icon] (loaded from package/windows/Facewizz.ico on class path) is what I get. Seems your logging comes from the Maven plugin. The more abstractions you make from the original build tools, the more opportunities to fail imho.

Comment: what version are you using of Java? I suddenly notice that when I build my app with the 7.0.17 the icon isn't set either. It is with the 7.0.12-ea release, so this was probably a bug that is going to be fixed in the bugfix release.

Comment: see also here https://blogs.oracle.com/talkingjavadeployment/entry/packaging_improvements_in_jdk_7 about fx:icon

Comment: yes ,using java7.0.17
the blog gives the detail to be added into build.xml file as my project donot contain any build.xml file as I am using maven so project contain an pom.xml where  its giving an error on tag <fx:deploy>

Comment: you need to put the fx:deploy task in ant file (build.xml) and call it from your pom using the maven-antrun-plugin plugin

Comment: i tried fx tags in pom.xml using ant. i have edited the post where i have added fx tags in maven-antrun-plugin but it wont give me custom package icon.

Comment: you should try with the 7.0.12-ea release

Answer (score 0):

```
     you can do this:
      `<plugin>
            <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>8.8.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <vendor>YourCompany</vendor>
                <mainClass>com.alan344.MapperGenApplication</mainClass>
                <appName>mybatis-friend</appName>
                <bundleArguments>
                    <icon>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/image/icon.ico</icon>
                </bundleArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>`
```

Comment: You should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57247918/edit) your question to add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) demonstrating the problem.