# How to set an app icon in JavaFX

Tags: deployment, javafx, icons

I am programming a JavaFX app for windows and want to see an app icon in these situations

1. shortcut icon (on desktop, windows start menu)
2. taskbar icon (even when the app is pinned to the task-bar)
3. (optional) the .exe-icon

The following code seems to do its job quite nice, but when the app is running and I press right to the taskbar to choose "pin this program" the default coffee cup is shown again. The cup is shown in the moment when the taskbar-item is right-clicked -.-

```
visibleStage.getIcons().add(new Image(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("JavaFXApp.png")));
```

I tried to build the app by configuring the Artifact in IntelliJ (JavaFX-plugin) and I also deployed the app with the javafx-maven-plugin...

I also followed some instructions I found in the net and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15880102/how-to-set-custom-icon-for-javafx-native-package-icon-on-windows) on stackoverflow, but nothing really helps (see [here](https://gyazo.com/fc4f1d51ce8ac10997387cb05806198e) to get an idea, what I tried).
Building the app by Ant doensnt work right now, IntelliJ gives a lot of errors using this build tool.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: 
It's getting silly.. After zooming in the output folder the correct .ico of the .exe will be shown. Inconstancy at it's best.

Here the half-working config:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Well, to add an icon to the app, you just need as you said to .add() an icon as:

```
primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("icon.png")));
```

For your installer, and all, I can't really help, but the way I do it works, I'm using innosetup to generate my  exe packages, and it's really easy to set it an icon. You can find informations about it on that site I learned about inno setup:

http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/part7/

The whole page is about deployment using ant and inno setup to build the exe

Comment: The installer is working (made it working with the javafx-maven-plugin).. but the app still shows the cup when I click-right onto the taskbar icon.

Comment: yes, thats not totally false - after I added multiple icon sizes to the stage, the clicking right will wont lead to the cup anymore. thanks for your answer. anyway... For the future I hope javafx provides more comfort in terms of setting an icon. This is really a pain...