# How to set custom icon for javafx native package icon in .exe file(i will answer all questions)

Tags: java, javafx, maven-plugin

I gonna cry,i don't know how to make this i have been in this for the last 8 hours of my life and i'm not capable to make this in solo.

i made the code part-per-part
here is my pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.br.eletra</groupId>
    <artifactId>Integration_Project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>8.6.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>main.Main</mainClass>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <vendor>Einstein</vendor>
                    <bundleArguments>
                        <identifier>UPDATE-DETECTION</identifier>
                        <installdirChooser>true</installdirChooser>
                    </bundleArguments>
                    <additionalAppResources>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</additionalAppResources>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>create-jar</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build-jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>create-native</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build-native</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.br.eletra</groupId>
            <artifactId>Integration_Project_Backend</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20230227</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

</project>
```

i cannot solve this question,why is this not working? i dont know please someone help me

and here is my .iss file:

```
[Setup]
AppId={{UPDATE-DETECTION}}
AppName=Integration_Project-1.0-SNAPSHOT
AppVersion=1.0
AppVerName=IntegrationProject-1.0-SNAPSHOT 1.0
AppPublisher=Einstein
AppComments=IntegrationProject-1.0
AppCopyright=Copyright (C) 2023
;AppPublisherURL=http://java.com/
;AppSupportURL=http://java.com/
;AppUpdatesURL=http://java.com/
DefaultDirName={localappdata}\Integration_Project-1.0-SNAPSHOT
DisableStartupPrompt=Yes
DisableDirPage=Yes
DisableProgramGroupPage=Yes
DisableReadyPage=Yes
DisableFinishedPage=Yes
DisableWelcomePage=Yes
DefaultGroupName=Einstein
;Optional License
LicenseFile=
;WinXP or above
MinVersion=6
OutputBaseFilename=IntegrationProject
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes
PrivilegesRequired=lowest
SetupIconFile=Integration_Project-1.0-SNAPSHOT\Integration_Project-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ico
UninstallDisplayIcon={app}\IntegrationProject-1.0.ico
UninstallDisplayName=Integration_Project-1.0-SNAPSHOT
WizardImageStretch=No
WizardSmallImageFile=Integration_Project-1.0-SNAPSHOT-setup-icon.bmp
ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode=



[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"
Name: "brazilianportuguese"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\BrazilianPortuguese.isl"

[Files]
Source: "Integration_Project-1.0-SNAPSHOT\Integration_Project-1.0-SNAPSHOT.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "Integration_Project-1.0-SNAPSHOT\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\Integration_Project-1.0-SNAPSHOT";Filename: "{app}\Integration_Project-1.0-SNAPSHOT.exe"; WorkingDir: "{app}"; IconFilename: "Integration_Project-1.0-SNAPSHOT-setup-icon.bmp"
Name: "{commondesktop}\Integration_Project-1.0-SNAPSHOT";Filename: "{app}\Integration_Project-1.0-SNAPSHOT.exe"; WorkingDir: "{app}"; IconFilename:"Integration_Project-1.0-SNAPSHOT-setup-icon.bmp"

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\Integration_Project-1.0-SNAPSHOT.exe"; Description:"{cm:LaunchProgram,Integration_Project-1.0-SNAPSHOT}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent;
Filename: "{app}\Integration_Project-1.0-SNAPSHOT.exe"; Parameters:"-install  -svcName ""Integration_Project-1.0-SNAPSHOT"" -svcDesc ""Integration_Project-1.0-SNAPSHOT"" -mainExe ""Integration_Project-1.0-SNAPSHOT.exe"" ";

[UninstallRun]
Filename: "{app}\Integration_Project-1.0-SNAPSHOT.exe "; Parameters: "-uninstall -svcName IntegrationProject-1.0 -stopOnUninstall";
```

can someone tell me why my .exe is with an random icon ?

Atualization: the windows dont find the .ico

Comment: [How to set custom icon for javafx native package icon on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15880102/how-to-set-custom-icon-for-javafx-native-package-icon-on-windows); [How to packaging javaFX with ICON](https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/post/how-to-packaging-javafx-with-icon-2255); [Self-Contained Application Packaging](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/self-contained-packaging.htm) (which is a bit of read if I'm honest)

Comment: Up-to-date documentation for modern technology which replaces some of the technologies referred to in the links is provided in the [Oracle `jpackage` user's guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/jpackage/packaging-overview.html#GUID-C1027043-587D-418D-8188-EF8F44A4C06A), which is also (unfortunately) a bit of a read.

Comment: Looking into it some more, your pom.xml appears to reference the [zenjava maven plugin](https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin).  That won't work for a modern JavaFX distribution 11+ and I don't think that it is maintained anymore.    The modern equivalent is the [openjfx javafx-maven-plugin](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-plugin), same name, different group.  It is however a different thing, and it will not do what you want - it will not build a native installer package for your application.

Comment: The [ackman JavaFX Maven plugin](https://akman.github.io/jpackage-maven-plugin/) is capable of creating a native installable package, with a `.exe` installer and, yes, with an icon :-). However, its use is by no means straightforward, examples are few and documentation is sparse.  I did this recently, so I could write a guide as an answer, but that is a lot of work, so I won't do that unless it is actually something you know that you need.  Alternatively, you can also look into [JPackageScriptFX](https://github.com/dlemmermann/JPackageScriptFX), which can help package native JavaFX apps.

Comment: However, if you wish to stick with Java 8, innosetup and the zenjava plugin for your application, then perhaps the links provided by MadProgrammer may work for you.  You are unlikely to receive a lot of additional support for such a technology stack though.